# How to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline job to use the same workspace

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have 2 pipeline jobs. JOB A & JOB B

I want to trigger JOB B to run on the same node and workspace of JOB A.

When I do so, Jenkins adds "@2" to the workspace of JOB B. for example:

```
JOB A workspace = /DATA/Jenkins_User/workspace/JOB-A 

JOB B receives the correct workspace as parameter,
```

but when I perform `ws(customWorkspace)` it is being built in

`/DATA/Jenkins_User/workspace/JOB-A@2`

Any idea how can I remove the "@2" characters?

Comment: The question here is more "why would you want to reuse another job's workspace ?". There must be cleaner way to accomplish your goal than to share a workspace which, by definition, is specific to a job. Please tell us more so we can help.

Comment: JOB A is a compile job. I want to separate the tests job from the compilation job and running on the same workspace is much faster for CI then archiving and copying artifacts between jobs.

Comment: my suggestion would be to use a single job which you can parametrized. With 2 boolean parameters "skipCompile" and "skipTests" you can have one single job doing the whole work by default, but then skip the tests or the compilation according to the moment.